# How to modify the shape of a stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, stroke, mask

I am trying to modify the "house" stroke by shaping the end of it. For now, it is shaped by the white triangle shape, but I want the white triangle to become transparent negative space. I have not been able to modify the stroke without messing with the gradient, but I don't want to rasterize the stroke. Is there any way I can turn the white triangle into a transparent mask that will still carve the end of the stroke?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please don't remove the images once you have your answer. The question may help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

Paint the triagle with pure black and put the green line behind it.

Select both and go to opacity and in its menu click Make Opacity mask.

Uncheck clip.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked into opacity masks earlier but I guess my minor mistake was not making the triangle black. It worked, I really appreciate it!